# Matlab edge detection problems - can I do it manually?

Tags: matlab, filtering, edge-detection

I have a set of roughly 2000 images to process, and have stumbled on a problem regarding my edges. The original images are CT Scans of a heart, which are then thresholded and sobel filtered to produce a binary image of parts of the tissue. Unfortunately the thresholding and filtering has resulted in certain images missing the 'edges' of the heart --> [R&LHS you can see the gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr7ds.png) & further down [Just a small one at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3sKO.png) hopefully this shows how annoying this is to do automatically

I've tried various inbuilt methods of edge detection, but the difference in size of the gaps makes it nearly impossible to do, without filling out the bits that are supposed to remain as gaps due to the sizes of the filters I use.

Is there a way of manually "connecting the dots" so to speak? It would take forever on the whole image set but seems to be my only option, or if you could suggest any other way of doing it would be cool!

Comment: This is very hard. One of the most open research fields is still image segmentation. Its very hard to make algorithms that will always catch everything and never leave gaps, as the algorithm itself does not knwo that this is a heart. To "fill the gaps" people use image erosion and dilation, but that will reduce the quality of the other borders

Comment: @AnderBiguri Hence why I'm looking for a manual way to define a section to fill. According to the documentation for 'imfill' using just `BW2 = imfill(BW);` should give an interactive window that allows me to select the boundary, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: It doesnt happen? Then your MATLAB is broken, but thats unlikely